# Why add claims in OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.GrantRefreshToken?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I'm configuring AspNet.Identity for OAuth 2 with bearer tokens and I have seen multiple examples of implementing the `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.GrantRefreshToken` method, where the author demonstrates the ability to add a claim to the `new ClaimsIdentity` as seen below.

I am trying to understand this in the context of my single-server (i.e. my Web API project is both Authorization + Resource server) which I may split into separate servers at a later date, if necessary.

```
public override Task GrantRefreshToken(OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context)
{
    var originalClient = context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary["as:client_id"];
    var currentClient = context.ClientId;

    if (originalClient != currentClient)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "Refresh token is issued to a different clientId.");
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    // Change auth ticket for refresh token requests
    var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Ticket.Identity);

    // CONSIDER: I don't know why you would add a claim here, but here's an example.
    //var newClaim = newIdentity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "newClaim").FirstOrDefault();
    //if (newClaim != null)
    //{
    //    newIdentity.RemoveClaim(newClaim);
    //}
    //newIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("newClaim", "newValue"));

    var newTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(newIdentity, context.Ticket.Properties);
    context.Validated(newTicket);

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthauthorizationserverprovider.grantrefreshtoken(v=vs.113).aspx) states:

"The application must call context.Validated to instruct the Authorization Server middleware to issue an **access token** based on those claims and properties."

I don't understand this. I thought we were handing out a refresh token, not an access token.

Also, "The call to context.Validated may be given a different AuthenticationTicket or ClaimsIdentity in order to control which information flows from the refresh token to the access token."

I thought all of the claims were stored in my signed and encrypted access token, which is passed as `Authorization: Bearer XXXXXX`. However, I have a tenuous grasp on how `ClaimsIdentity` and `AuthenticationTicket` actually relate to anything in my OAuth 2.0 flow.

My best guess is that `GrantRefreshToken` needs to take the already authenticated and authorized identity (`context.Ticket.Identity`) and validate that a refresh token should be added to it by calling context.Validated.

Comment: Yes, you send an refresh token, but based on this refresh token the server emitts the access token. So if you dont call Validated, you will at the end not get an access token.
`The call to context.Validated may be given a different AuthenticationTicket or ClaimsIdentity in order to control which information flows from the refresh token to the access token. The default behavior when using the OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider is to flow information from the refresh token to the access token unmodified.`
So, default is not to add further claims here --> unmodified. This is how I understand it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refresh Tokens in OAuth2 are just another type of grant: an alternative method of obtaining a new `access_token`.

For this reason the `RefreshToken` must be validated in order to emit a new `access_token` for the user.

When persisting the refresh token to the underlying storage (e.g. a database) the entire user identity must be stored along with it (usually using `SerializeTicket()` method of the `AuthenticationTokenCreateContext` object). This means that any change in the claims acquired during the first `access_token` generation will not be propagated to other `access_token`s emissions using the `RefreshToken` grant by default (you will need to reload again those claims if you need to update them in the `access_token`).

I believe this is the main reason why many examples shows how to add/substitute claims in the new Identity inside the `GrantRefreshToken` method.

I will try to further clarify what usually happens when supporting the `RefreshTokenGrant`:

1. The user authenticates himself using any kind of supported grant (e.g. `ResourceOwnerCredentials`);
2. We create an Identity bounded to this specific user (we can add Claims at this point) and use it to create a new `AuthenticationTicket` (that we validate by calling `Validated(ticket)` on the specific `context` object) which will be used to create the `access_token`;
3. The framework generates a new refresh token calling `CreateAsync` on the provided `IAuthenticationTokenProvider`. Inside this method we have to retrieve the ticket and store it into some kind of persistence storage (e.g. a DB) along with an unique `Id` and some useful metadata. This `Id` is the `refresh_token` for the user point of view.
4. We return to the user the `access_token` (which contains the serialized claims for the user) and the `refresh_token` (which is just a reference).
5. After some time the user must authenticate again (e.g. the `access_token` expired), so he will send a request to the Token endpoint using the `refresh_token`.
6. We retrieve the `refresh_token` record from the persistent storage and deserialize the ticket that will be used to create a new Identity. This ticket contains all Claims that we added on the first authentication (this is almost an exact copy of the first `access_token`): if any of those Claims changed during the interval between the current moment and the first authentication (e.g. a new Role is added to the user, email has changed, etc.) we have now the chance to modify the new Identity and add/substitute those Claims, so that the new `access_token` will reflect the changes.
7. The flows continues by validating the ticket (as before) and generating a pair of `access_token` and `refresh_token` to send to the user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't make sense to me because right now, I am NOT adding any claims in the `GrantRefreshToken` overload. I am only adding claims in my `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`. For instance - `identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"))`. However, when my access token expires and I get a new one with the refresh token, I am still able to call Web API routes that are protected with `[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]`.

Comment: I'm confused by two things in your answer. The part where you say "When persisting this token...the entire user identity is stored along with it" Do you mean to say that the entire identity is actually encoded within the *access* token itself? This is what I understand to be true but it sounds like you're talking about Database persistence (but maybe both). The other part I'm confused by is where you say "...any **change** in the claims...". So in other words - if the user is suddenly added to a different role, etc... they won't get that new role unless I add them in `GrantRefreshToken`?

Comment: I cannot be be more specific because I can't see your implementation, but what is usually done in many tutorials (e.g. in the [Taiseer's one](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/)) is to persist the refresh token metadata, along with its serialized ticket (`context.SerializeTicket();`) into some kind of storage (e.g. a DB), so you can retrieve and deserialize the ticket to create a new Identity afterwards. This ticket contains the entire User Identity (including claims).

Comment: Edited my answer to further clarify what usually happens in your scenario.

Comment: Thank you @Federico Dipuma. I understand the process that you've described. The only difficulty that I'm having is aligning that with the actual methods from my project which are based off of Taiseer's article that you linked to. When my client code has an expired `access_token` and then uses its `refresh_token` to get a new `access_token`, here are the order of calls that I see - `AuthServerProvider.ValidateClientAuthentication(); AuthRefreshTokenProvider.ReceiveAsync(); AuthServerProvider.GrantRefreshToken(); AuthServerProvider.TokenEndpoint(); AuthRefreshTokenProvider.CreateAsync();`

Comment: OK, comparing this to what happens when a user logs in, I can see how it all works now. Here is the order of calls when the user logs in - if you align these call lists next to each other verticall you can clearly see the difference - `AuthServerProvider.ValidateClientAuthentication();
AuthServerProvider.GrantResourceOwnerCredentials();
AuthServerProvider.TokenEndpoint();
AuthRefreshTokenProvider.CreateAsync();`